# Keep text in lift snippet

Tags: scala, lift

there is a lift snippet:

```
<lift:Login>
  <entry:name>
     No user logged in
  </entry:name>
</lift:Login>
```

I know that I can `Helpers.bind` the user name if the user is logged in, but how can I preserve the former text enclosed in ? There seems to be no support to project prefixed elements when I see scala api, `xhtml \\ "entry:name"` yields nothing more than empty Node. So how can I accomplish such goal?
EDIT:
In case when the user is logged, I want to show:
`User 123`
In the other case, I want to show the original text in snippet, in other words, I want to just remove the lift prefixed tags which are indispensable for framework, but they have nothing to do in end user html :
`No user logged in`

Comment: Why do you want to preserve the former text?

Comment: I want to achieve behaviour: when no user is logged in, the default text is displayed which is "No user logged in" in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not clear what you’ve tried already but in most cases there is no need for Scala xml transformations. Using `Helpers.bind` is usually sufficient and can deal with xml prefixes properly. (Scala’s xml transformations API sometimes feels a bit uneven in this respect.)

Not 100% sure what you want to do but this is how I’d bind the user name to `<entry:name/>` if logged in or else show the default text.

```
class Login {
  def render(xhtml: NodeSeq) = bind("entry", xhtml, "name" -> name _)
  def name(in: NodeSeq) = User.currentUser.map(_.shortName).map(Text(_)) openOr in
}
```

**Addition**:
The `"name" -> name _` part means that the method `name` should be called with the contents of the `<entry:name>` tag and the result should replace the whole tag. (I must say, I’m not quite sure what you already know about lift; my impression is that if one knows how to bind `User 123` one should also know how to bind other information…)

The trailing underscore is needed to help the compiler here. If you don’t want to do a transformation of the original content of the tag, you’d simply bind a `val` or a `def someMethod: NodeSeq` and then use it without underscore or even inline. E.g. `bind("entry", xhtml, "name" -> <span>Some NodeSeq</span>)`

Comment: but this wont remove the lift tags, so the user would see some <lift:entry>No user logged in</lift:entry>.

Comment: <lift:entry>? It replaces the <entry:name> tags. That’s what `Helpers.bind` is all about.

Comment: could you, please, explain, what is happening in this part `"name" -> name _`?