# In (Scala) Lift, how to render the original HTML from the template when using Helpers.bind

Tags: templates, scala, bind, lift, helper

I'm a Scala/Lift beginner and I'm having trouble with rendering a list with optional "tags" on each item.

My HTML template says

```
<lift:Items.list>
  <e:name>Rock</e:name><br />
  <e:warning><span style="color:#ff0000;">DANGER!</span></e:warning>
</lift:Items.list>
```

And on the Items.scala I have

```
def list(node : NodeSeq) : NodeSeq = {

  getItems flatMap( it => {

     Helpers.bind("e", node,
                  "name" -> { Text(it.name) },
                  "warning" -> { 
                      if (it.isDangerous) { <<INSERT HTML FROM TEMPLATE>> } 
                      else { Text("") }
                         }
                  )
  })
}
```

I'd like to, in certain cases, have the contents of the "e:warning" tag rendered verbatim. I'm sure there's an easy way to extract them from "node", but I guess I have some major gaps in my Lift knowledge because I can't figure out how.
If anyone could point out the proper procedure to me I'd be very thankful.

---

ANSWERED:
Thanks for the advice. I ended up structuring my code like this:

```
    "warning" -> { (n : NodeSeq) => {
                  if (it.isDangerous) { n } else { Text("") }
                 }}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply bind a function to the node’s name which takes a `NodeSeq` and returns a `NodeSeq`.

E.g.:

```
def warning(in: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = doSomethingWith(in)

// ...

Helpers.bind("e", node, "warning" -> warning _)
```

The contents of the `<e:warning>` node will then be transformed and inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the purpose of what you are trying to do. If you want to display one thing or the other, use chooseTemplate and a Box.